# How can I get the search parameters from jqgrid in the server side?

Tags: jqgrid

I've been visiting this forum a lot without registering since several months ago, and I really like it. So, thanks in advance to all the members. Now I'd like to make my first question.

I've been using Jqgrid for a few time, and I've managed to have it display the rows and buttons, but now I need to do a search, a complex one, and I thought that "automatically" jqgrid would send the parameters to the server, I mean:

> sField, searchField, sOper, searchOper, sValue, searchString, sFilter and/or filters

I'm not sure at all which ones it has to send, and I thought it would be just the same as it sends 'page', 'rows' and 'sord'. But I'm missing something, because, for example, I can get 'page', 'rows' and 'sord' using:

```
$limit = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rows', 10);
```

but I get nothing by using:

```
$params = $_REQUEST['filters']
```

or

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sFilter');
```

I'm using PHP, Zend and json.

I didn't post any code because my doubt is kind of generic, but I will do it if it was needed.

I've searched a lot, and read the documentation, but I just don't see it. I will appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll respond to my own question just to share. I just added 'loadonce' and it worked.

This is a version of my actual javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var filtro = {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Col1","op":"eq","data":""},
                                   {"field":"Col3","op":"eq","data":""}
                                   {"field":"Col4","op":"eq","data":""}]};

$("#lista").jqGrid( {
    url:'/module/controller/json-action',
    datatype: "json",
    postData: { filters: JSON.stringify(filtro) },
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:[, 'Col1', 'Col2','Col3','Col4'],
    colModel:[  
                {name:'N°',index:'ID', width:60, align:"center", hidden:true},
                {name:'Col1',index:'Col1', width:150, search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] } },
                {name:'Col2',index:'Col2', width:250, align:"left", search:false},
                {name:'Col3',index:'Col3', width:120, align:"left", search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] }},
                {name:'Col4',index:'Col4', width:60, align:"center", search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] }}]
    , rowNum:10
    , rowList:[10,20,30]
    , pager: '#pager'
    , sortname: 'ID'
    , viewrecords: true
    , sortorder: "desc"
    , caption:"Listado de ejemplo"
    , loadonce: true
    , onSelectRow: function(id) {
         $("#ID").val(id);
      }
    , ondblClickRow: function(id) {
        $("#edit").submit();
    }
}); 

$("#lista").jqGrid(
        'navGrid', '#pager', { edit:false, add:false, del:false }, 
        {},// settings for edit
        {},// settings for add
        {},// settings for delete
        {   multipleSearch:true/*activa la búsqueda avanzada*/, 
            closeAfterSearch:true, closeAfterReset:true, recreateFilter:true,
            /*la función que define la búsqueda*/
            onSearch: function() {}//fin onSearch
            ,
            //the search criteria that user selected before pressing find use below code:
            onClose:function() {
            }//fin onClose

        }
);

});//fin document ready
```

All I did was just to add "loadonce: true". if I remove "loadonce: true", the grid won't filter anymore.